# Error de nestable en modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, lista, modal

Al arrastrar un ítem me lo muestra atrás del modal

Aqui el modal y dentro de el agrego el nestable, tambien agrego la imagen donde muestra que al arrastrar el ítem (sin soltarlo) me lo muestra atrás del modal.

```
div class="modal " id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header no-padding">                
            <h2 class="blue smaller color-blue center">Ordenar</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="widget-box transparent">

                        <div class="widget-body">
                            <div class="widget-main padding-4">
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="dd" id="nestable">
                                                <ol class="dd-list listact">
                                                    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
                                                        <div class="dd-handle">
                                                            Item 1
                                                            <i class="pull-right bigger-130 ace-icon fa fa-exclamation-triangle orange2"></i>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>

                                                    <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
                                                        <div class="dd-handle">Item 2</div>
                                                    </li>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="space-6"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="text-right">
                                    <h4 class="widget-title smaller green">
                                        <button type="button" class="pull-Middle btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-white btn-round submitBtn" data-dismiss="modal">
                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-times red2"></i>
                                            Cancelar
                                        </button>

                                        <button type="button" class="pull-Middle btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-white btn-round submitBtn" id="btnGuardarNewFlujo">
                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check-square-o bigger-110 green"></i>
                                            Guardar
                                        </button>

                                    </h4>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inicializo nestable() al activar el modal y lo configuro para que el numero de niveles sea 1, solo para que el usuario ordene los ítems, Lo que se necesita es que al arrastrar un item (si soltarlo) me muestre encima del modal y no atrás.

```
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('.dd').nestable({ maxDepth: 1 });
  $('.dd-handle a').on('mousedown', function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

[image: img]

Como hacer para que muestre el ítem adelante del modal al arrastrarlo.
Desde ya Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código `HTML` (_por las dudas, en texto, no en imagen_)?